# How to select the default contenttype/pagelayout for each new article page by the right top corner custom action?

Tags: content-type, page-layout

In the right top corner you can click on the icon, and then click on "Create new Page". You will see a new popup and can enter the name of the page. After you click on OK you will get into the new page in edit mode. I see here some page from some contenttype/pagelayout. Is it possible to change this default to another contenttype/pagelayout?

Comment: Site Settings -> Page Layouts and Site Templates?

Comment: My contenttype/pagelayout is there already. Do I need to set it as first. Is it maybe the order?

Comment: I found it. Is this also possible programmatically?

Comment: It can be set programmatically. I remember doing it in a feature receiver in a past project. I don't have that code available though.